# Ned help drawing a dfa from this hypothesis?

Tags: java, theory, computation-theory, dfa

This DFA accepts any string over the alphabet {a, b} where the number of 'b's, if present, is even.  An example of strings it accept:
Accepted:
a
aa
bb
aaa
abb
bab
bba
aaa
abb
bab
bba
aaaa
aaab
aabab
baaab
aabab
baaab
babaa
bbaaa
aaabab
aaaa
aabab
bbaaa
bbbb
aaaa

Ive tried dfas with states, 3 states, I just can't get it to work.

Comment: What have your attempts looked like? It doesn't seem like there are that many options for a basic implementation--the `A`s don't matter, and you're toggling between two states based on whether there's an odd number of `B`s, or zero/even `B`s.

Comment: Would two states, q0 as the start/accept state and q1 work with both having self loops of a and b going between both work?

Comment: AFAIK yes--by "not many options" I mean "the basic implementation is straight-forward" which means you may be over-thinking this.

Comment: yes I was over thinking it, you pointing it out helped actually. Thank you.

Comment: how would you write L = {w | w is a string over the alphabet {a, b} and if w contains any 'b's, it has an even number of 'b's} where it looks correct in terms of format of a langauge hypothesis

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.